# How do I change the values of a radio button from 1, 2, 3, etc to text values?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have created a small database in Access 2007 that consists of one table and two forms, one for entering data, and one for retrieving data.

My problem is this: On my input form I have a group box with three radio buttons in it.  The question being asked is **Is the element a sensor?**
The buttons represent **Yes**, **No**, and **Don’t Know**.

In the database I have a column named Sensor to hold the value the user chose, but since the radio buttons return a value of **1** for *yes*, **2** for *no*, or **3** for *don't know*, it makes generating a report or query that makes sense to the user very difficult.

At this point I’m writing huge SQL statements with nested iif’s to return the data the way I want to see it.

Is there a way to populate the table with data the way I want to see it (yes, no, don’t know) instead of populating it with 1’s 2’s or 3’s?  This is a bound form by the way, I wish I would have done it unbound, but I can’t go back now.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using the radio buttons, and instead opt for a combo box. You'll be able to use string values for the results directly in the combo box.

Now if you are dead set on using radio buttons, try this:

Add a new field to your table that holds text. Bind this to a hidden text box on your form.
Then, add a BeforeUpdate event (or AfterUpdate depending on what you are doing) to the radio group. Add code similar to the following:

```
Sub RadioGroup_BeforeUpdate(cancel As Integer)
    Select Case Me.RadioGroup.Value
        case 1
            Me.hiddenTextField.value = "Yes"
        case 2
            Me.hiddenTextField.value = "No"
        case else
            Me.hiddenTextField.value = "Don't Know"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Now when you save the record, the human readable value will be available in the new field you added.

Comment: I am stuck with the radio buttons, thats how the boss wants it. I love the solution you came up with and I will give that a try, thank you so much!

Comment: You suggested a de-normalized table.  Still it could work reasonably well as long as data edits are made exclusively through the form (or forms).  If changes can occur by other methods (bulk import, edit table directly, etc.) the stored numbers and text descriptors can easily get out of sync.  And that would not be A Good Thing.

Comment: @HansUp You are correct. I think OP just wanted to human text versions in the first place though. That being said though, he could even unbind the radio group; using it solely to set the hidden text field and remove the numerical version already in the table.

Comment: True, but that would then require more work (code) to assign the current value to the unbound option group when navigating between existing rows.  I'm NOT claiming it can't be done ... just why is it even really worth the effort?  Just store the number per The Access Way, and when you need to see text equivalents, join to the lookup table. It's all quite simple and relational.

Comment: Also unbound controls don't fit so well when the form is in continuous or datasheet view.

Answer (score 2):

"*since the radio buttons return a value of 1 for yes, 2 for no, or 3 for don't know, it makes generating a report or query that makes sense to the user very difficult.*"

Store those 3 pairs as rows in a `Sensor_Values` table:

```
sval descriptor
1    yes
2    no
3    don't know
```

Then you can join that table to the table which includes the stored `Sensor` numbers.

```
SELECT yt.Sensor, sv.descriptor
FROM
    YourTable AS yt
    INNER JOIN Sensor_Values AS sv
    ON yt.Sensor = sv.sval;
```

If you're opposed to creating and joining a lookup table, you could use a `Switch()` expression in your queries to translate the numeric `Sensor` values to their text forms.

```
SELECT
    Switch(
        Sensor = 1, "yes",
        Sensor = 2, "no",
        Sensor = 3, "don't know"
    ) AS sensor_text
FROM YourTable;
```

The `Switch()` approach can work, but can be more challenging to maintain compared to the lookup table approach.

My intention here was to show you fairly simple methods to use the option group value as a number instead of "*populate the table with data the way I want to see it (yes, no, don’t know) instead of populating it with 1’s 2’s or 3’s*"

As a general rule, you will be better off working with Access controls as they were designed to be used.  Break that rule whenever you have a compelling reason ... but breaking the rule then requires additional efforts from you ... like more VBA code.  The approaches I suggested don't require any VBA.

Comment: That is actually what I was looking for. I had read you coud do it by creating another table with a join, but I just wasnt quite sure how to do it. I will see if I can get this to work. Thank you so much!

Comment: Experiment with the query designer.  Add the two tables and drag the link field from one table to its link partner in the other table.  That should create a join line between the two.  You can then switch to SQL View to see the actual SQL syntax for the join.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a `Select Case` when creating the select string, instead of having `iif`'s nested in the SQL.

```
Select Case Me.rdoSensor
    Case 1
        sSQL=sSQL & " AND Sensor='Yes'"
    Case 2
        sSQL=sSQL & " AND Sensor='No'"
    Case 3
        sSQL=sSQL & " AND Sensor='Don''t know'"
End Select
```